# Semantic Error with If ,elif, and else statements

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

Hello to anyone this message may reach. I am having issues with a semantic error that I just cant quite figure out.  I am very new to coding and I am trying to learn python 3.  I am trying to create a code that lets me know if I have to work on a particular day of the week.  I have done this by using if statements but I cannot get the code to go to the else or elif for some reason. Any and all answers will be helpful. Thanks in advance.

```
week_day_1 = "Monday"
week_day_2 = "Tuesday"
week_day_3 = "Wednesday"
week_day_4 = "Thursday"
half_week_day = "Friday"
weekend_day_1 = "Saturday"
weekend_day_2 = "Sunday"
week_days = week_day_1, week_day_2, week_day_3, week_day_4
weekend_days = weekend_day_1, weekend_day_2
weekend_days = True
week_days = True
half_week_day = True
input("What day of the week is it?") #the input allows the user to insert the day of the week.
if week_days:
    print("You must go to work.")
elif weekend_days:
    print("It is the weekend. Enjoy your time off.")
elif half_week_day:
    print("You must go to work, but your weekend start once you clock out.")
else:
    print("Please enter day of the week.")**
```

No matter what day I input the code returns back "You must go to work"

Comment: You aren't saving the result of `input()` to anything.

Comment: You never bind the value, input from user to a name, just throw it away

Comment: Also, note that you create a tuples and bind them to `week_days` and `weekend_days`, then replace them with bool `True` value.

Comment: You're not comparing the user's input to any of those tuples.

Comment: The reason you can't get your code to go into the `else` or `elif` branches is that you have set `week_days` to True unconditionally, so the `if` branch of your `if/elif/elif/else statement `will **always be executed** and so none of your elif/elif/else branches will **ever be executed**..  You have a lot wrong with your code, but the answer to your specific question involves just two lines:  `week_days = True` and `if week_days:`.

Comment: You have some basic misunderstandings about how variables work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3 main problems with your code (thers more):

**1. `week_days = week_day_1, week_day_2, week_day_3, week_day_4` should be a list with brackets.**

**2. You assert a boolean value to these variable after assert list to them.**

**3. There is no examination of the input. There is only an examination of the boolean values which are always True**.

Here is a code that will work:

```
half_week_day = "Friday"
week_days = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday"]
weekend_days = ["Saturday", "Sunday"]

day = input("What day of the week is it?") #the input allows the user to insert the day of the week.
if day in week_days:
    print("You must go to work.")
elif day in weekend_days:
    print("It is the weekend. Enjoy your time off.")
elif day == half_week_day:
    print("You must go to work, but your weekend start once you clock out.")
else:
    print("Please enter day of the week.")
```

Comment: Any specific reason to keep normal variables and list both, could not we store the week days directly on list?

Comment: @AlwaysSunny 100% I just fixed his code. But you are right.

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign the user's input to a variable, then you can compare it to the tuples you've created.

For consistency I've changed `half_week_day` to `half_week_days`, and made it a tuple (putting a `,` after `week_day_5` in the assignment).

The assignments like `week_days = True` are replacing the tuples that list each type of day. They aren't needed.

```
week_day_1 = "Monday"
week_day_2 = "Tuesday"
week_day_3 = "Wednesday"
week_day_4 = "Thursday"
week_day_5 = "Friday"
weekend_day_1 = "Saturday"
weekend_day_2 = "Sunday"
week_days = week_day_1, week_day_2, week_day_3, week_day_4
weekend_days = weekend_day_1, weekend_day_2
half_week_days = week_day_5,
today = input("What day of the week is it?") #the input allows the user to insert the day of the week.
if today in week_days:
    print("You must go to work.")
elif today in weekend_days:
    print("It is the weekend. Enjoy your time off.")
elif today in half_week_day:
    print("You must go to work, but your weekend start once you clock out.")
else:
    print("Please enter day of the week.")
```

Answer (score 1):

**The main reason your existing code is not working is because you are not saving the input value and comparing that further**, that's why it is executing the last `else` every time. If I were you I would use this way to do the task-

```
week_days = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday"]
weekend_days = ["Saturday", "Sunday"]
half_week_day = "Friday"    
day_name = input(
        "What day of the week is it?"
)  # the input allows the user to insert the day of the week.
if day_name in week_days:
    print("You must go to work.")
elif day_name in weekend_days:
    print("It is the weekend. Enjoy your time off.")
elif day_name == half_week_day:
    print("You must go to work, but your weekend start once you clock out.")
else:
    print("Please enter day of the week.")
```

**Explanation,**

**1.** I used [list](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list) to store `week_days` instead of multiple variables.

**2.** I used a new variable that will store the user [input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26779091/python-save-user-inputs-in-new-variables) data so I can use it to compare with the existing `week_days`, `weeked_days`, and `half_week_day`.

**3.** I used [in](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/operators) which will help us to check if a value exists in multiple values.

Answer (score -1):

`if weekdays` basically checks for the "truthyness" of an object in python. Since `weekdays` is an array with elements in it this will evaluate to True (whereas an empty array would evaluate to False e.g. `if [] == False`)

what you want to do is assign your input to a variable like `day_to_check` and then you want to check if this day is IN these arrays.

e.g:

```
day_to_check = "Monday"
if day_to_check in weekdays:
    ...
```

I'd recommend writing a script for this and using `argparse`, chekc out how to use `if **name** == "**main**" when writing the script and google argparse.

Also, you can make this a bit easier/less boilerplate by using the `calendar` module in python:

```
import calendar

print(calendar.day_name[0])
>>>Monday
```

Comment: Your analysis is incorrect.  By the time that the `if` statement is executed, `week_days` has been reassigned the value `True`.